# Inverting first and last name in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got a .plist that has the names of people that I want to use formatted like the following:

```
<key>Name</key>
<string>Doe, John</string>
```

I would really like it if the names would show up as John Doe instead of Doe, John. Similar to the way that you get rid of spaces in links, is there a method that I can use to easily accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like fairly simple string processing.  My Objective-C is a but rusty, but the following should work (untested):

```
NSString *name = @"Doe, John";
NSArray *lastFirst = [name componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
NSString *formattedName = [[[lastFirst objectAtIndex:1] stringByAppendingString: @" "] stringByAppendingString:[lastFirst objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: Assuming the ", " is strictly enforced in the plist, yes, use this.

Comment: Good call @darvids0n. Yes, in the inconsistent formatting case, should split by "," and trim spacing.  Also called attention to the fact that I wasn't putting a space between the first and last names, which is now fixed.